# How to Use Object Destructuring with File Object

Tags: javascript

how to destructure an object like this?

```
File {name: "file.png", lastModified: 1607110320000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Dec 
04 2020 11:32:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 
44887, …}
```

is a File from a FileList. I was able to iterate but that last part is missing

```
[...files].forEach((file, index) => (
    console.log({...file})
))}
```

but I get an empty object `{}`

Comment: That’s because a `File` has no own properties.

Comment: but if I do file.name it shows the.. file name

Comment: And `name` isn’t an own property. It’s a getter on `File.prototype`.

Comment: can I convert it like to an object and then destructure it? is similar to `FileList` I converted it to an array with `[...files]` right? thanks!

Comment: What do you expect from using `{...file}` in the first place?

Comment: pass it to my react component `<MyComponent {...file} />` w

Comment: How about simply the properties you want destructured? `const {name, size, type, ...} = file`

Comment: There's no destructuring in your code. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @handsome Passing it as props to a jsx component is a completely different thing, and actually has to do neither with destructuring nor with object spread syntax (even if the jsx syntax looks similar). But really I would recommend to just use `<MyComponent file={file} />`.

Answer (score 0):

Spreading the File object is not possible as it has no own properties,but you can destructure the File object and get the properties you need.

```
const { name, size } = FileObj
```